# JavaScript RegEx, alphanumeric with asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i search for a regex in JavaScript for Alphanumeric characters and the asterisk sign (*).

All i found is this:

```
  var regexAlphaNumWithAsterisk = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-zA-Z\*{*}]+$/);
```

I want to test this groups : "12*****" or "123456" or "BCDEFG" or "12*ABC" 
When I change my regexp like

```
var regexAlphaNum = new RegExp(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/);
```

my validation for "123456" or "BCDEFG" is fine.

Can everyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use regex literal for this:

```
var regexAlphaNum = /^[0-9a-zA-Z*]+$/;
```

No need to use `RegExp` constructor for this and `*` doesn't need to be escaped inside character class i.e. `[...]`

Comment: How about `/^[0-9a-z*]+$/i`